# What is the number after `Thread-`?

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory

I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-129352114" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

- What is the number `129352114`?
- Is it random?

In fact, I am digging into the `OutOfMemoryError`. There are two possible reasons: 1, no enough memory; 2, two many threads. For the *gc* log files, it seems that there are enough heap size. There may be too many threads. But from log file, I cannot figure out the number of threads when the error happened. I've no idea whether `129352114` can tell something or not.

Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: If you don't name your threads, they will use `Thread-` + an id, starting with 1 and increasing by one for each new Thread. It doesn't surprise me that you got an OOM with that number of threads. Consider using Thread Pools.

Answer (score 0):

It is a secuential number for each Thread created in that VM. It's the default name given to new threads.

Despite this, you can give names to threads yourself, and it is not unusual to find some libraries and tools which do this.